# CSS3 does ::after inherit the height and margin of the origin element in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-element

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="demo">hello world</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
 .demo { width: 100px; 
         height: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; 
         background-color: red; position: relative;
         z-index:-1;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorStr=#40ffffff,EndColorStr=#12ffffff);zoom: 1;}
 .demo::after { 
         width: 95px; 
         height: 95px; 
         position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; border: 5px solid blue; content:""; 
         background-color: yellow; opacity: .75;}
```

I wanted the pseudo element to completely cover the origin element (which contains a 50% gradient for IE7,8 - therefore height: 50%, margin-bottom: 50%;)

However in IE9... the ::after element only covers 50%, although I specifically set the height to be 44px. Is this because of the use of filter? Any idea how to override it?

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/otilux/2/edit) of the example.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of the whole thing:

[Example](http://www.franckreich.de/x/members/index_back.html)

Notes:

- see comments in the background.css file
- I can't change the element structure or assign gradient to any other element than .ui-icon
- The gradient should cover 50% of the footer. Footer is 44px so gradient stops at 22px
- IE7+8 cannot do this (or color stops), so I making .ui-icon height 22px plus filter-gradient
- using ::before I add the gradient for all other browsers sitting on top of .ui-icon

Problem 1 = IE9+ renders ::before - I use z-index:-1, so .ui-icon sits behind ::before = OK

Problem 2 = on IE9+ the ::before background is cut off by .ui-icon.

Question: How can I avoid the gradient in ::before being cut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of the use of filter? Any idea how to override it?

Yes, it's because of the `filter`. Using `filter` causes an `overflow:hidden`-esque effect.

You might be aware that `:after` is rendered inside the element, like this:

```
<div class="demo">hello world<div:after></div:after></div>
```

If you add `overflow: hidden`, then all browsers are equally broken: http://jsbin.com/otilux/3

---

So, how to fix it? One option is to use `::before` to handle drawing the thing that has `filter`.

**See:** http://jsbin.com/otilux/4

That looks the same as it did before in Chrome/Firefox, and now also looks the same in IE9.

Due to using `::after` instead of `:after`, I can see you're not trying to support IE8. So, another option would be to use an [SVG gradient instead of `filter`](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/).

Comment: Thanks! Some stuff I wasn't aware of. 

I'm trying to do a 50% top-to-bottom gradient cross browser (including IE7,8). Since IE does not do 50% stop I placed the IE7,8 gradient in the original element, reduced height to 50% and used the IE-filter-gradient. Then I used ::before to place an element above the original element, which contains the gradient syntax for all other browsers.

OK IE7,8 with the original element,
OK FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari using the ::before element,
BREAKS IE9+ because my ::before gradient gets cut off. 

Therefore asking.

Checking your input...

Comment: Can you show me the version that works in Chrome/Firefox complete with gradient?

Comment: ..also, why are you using `::after` if you need to support IE7? `:before`/`::before`/`:after`/`::after` - none of them work in IE7.

Comment: I forgot about this, sorry. Do you still need help?

Comment: As a matter of fact... Yes. 

Here is the link to the just completed example:
http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html

If you open it in IE9, you will see the button-background and icon-background don't match, because... (I'm guessing)
a) .ui-icon::before inherits the height of .ui-icon in IE9+ only
b) .ui-icon is in front of .ui-icon::before in IE9+ only